# Windows server 2012 R2 - Memory in use is more than commit charge

Tags: windows, memory

One of our Windows server reported 100% memory usage and please see the attached image for details.

What I don't understand is that "In use (31.5G)" is more than "commit charge(6.6G)", does that mean something is wrong or because some memory in use is not pageable?

[image]

Comment: In this context I think "In use" is referring to total physical RAM being used, whereas "committed", refers to the virtual address space commit charge / commit charge limit. So no, I wouldn't say something is wrong, you're just running out of RAM

Comment: If possible download [RamMap from microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/rammap.aspx) and post a image of the "Use Counts" tab.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that helped, there are 28G of mapped files. I am still surprised that resource monitor does not show it at all. Anyway thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

"Commit charge" is the sum of the virtual address space allocated privately to all processes, plus some system-wide allocations like the nonpaged pool. The system-wide limit on commit charge is given by the sum of RAM + pagefile space; however, a given "commit charge" does not necessarily mean that all of that space is actually in use, either in RAM or in the pagefile. Thus the "commit charge" can greatly exceed the actual RAM that it's using (even if you don't have a pagefile).

But there are many other things that use RAM. "In use" is the total of all processes' use of RAM (of which the in-memory subset of each process's commit charge is only part; most of the remainder is typically file mappings), plus all of the system-wide usage.

So it is not at all unexpected for commit charge to be much smaller than the RAM "in use". It isn't really supposed to be the same. For that matter it's also possible for commit charge to be larger than the RAM "in use" (if a lot of committed memory has been allocated but not yet referenced, hence not "faulted in", i.e. realized in RAM).